# Unable to display geojson data on a leaflet map in a Django app

Tags: leaflet, data, geojson, geodjango, django

I'm developing a Django application using Django-leaflet and Postgresql / PostGIS. I retrieve the data in views.py and I convert them in GeoJSON format  using Django's serializer.
My views.py:

```
from geonode.geoloc.models import Transport
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.serializers import serialize
import json, ast


class LookupView(FormView):
    template_name = 'geoloc/lookupresults.html'
    form_class = LookupForm

    def get(self, request):
        return render_to_response('geoloc/lookup.html',  RequestContext(request))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Get data
        latitude = form.cleaned_data['latitude']
        longitude = form.cleaned_data['longitude']

        # Look up roads
        roads =  Transport.objects.all()[0:5]

        roads_json = serialize('geojson', roads,
               fields=('geom',))

        # I remove crs key because it is not recommended by http://geojsonlint.com/
        new_roads_json = json.loads(roads_json)
        new_roads_json.pop('crs', None)
        new_roads_json = json.dumps(new_roads_json)

        # Render the template
        return self.render_to_response({
                          'new_roads_json': new_roads_json
                         })
```

My template when the form is valid:

```
{% extends "geoloc/geoloc_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% leaflet_js %}
{% leaflet_css %}

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
  var geojsonFeature = ["{{ new_roads_json }}"];
  var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(mymap);

  var myroads = L.geoJSON().addTo(mymap);
  myroads.addData(geojsonFeature);

  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And my models.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Transport(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aa = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    geom = models.MultiLineStringField(srid=2100, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'transport'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name or u''
```

When I send the data while geojson content is valid, nothing is displayed on the leaflet map.
Also, no errors in browser's developer tools / firebug or in my django development server.
To test if geojson object that serializer creates is valid, I sended the data as a text with:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = geojsonFeature
```

That geojson text, I posted in http://geojsonlint.com/ and the geometry was displayed on the map with no errors.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the issue. The problem came from the following line:

```
var geojsonFeature = ["{{ new_roads_json }}"];
```

I put the square brackets because without them it raised invalid objects errors. Thus, I thought that it was the right syntax. Finally, I figured out that the real problem was that the system translated the quotation " as &quot. So, I added the 'safe' Django filter. The second problem was that it doesn't need quotation and square brackets.
So I converted the above line to:

```
var geojsonFeature = {{ new_roads_json|safe }};
```

And the problem solved. Two very useful links that helped me to solve the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/